# Jenkins failed: Test reports were found but none of them are new. Did tests run?

Tags: linux, bash, jenkins, junit, report

I'm testing the Jenkins jUnit plugin with a manual jUnit Xml file. And I get following info from console output

> failed: Test reports were found but none of them are new. Did tests run?

I've searched the solution for this problem but none of them solve my confuse. I try to run a shell script. Since I'm pretty new to this(might have a lot of errors). Here is a piece of my shell script.

```
cd /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/jUnitReport
sudo visudo
Jenkins ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/sh -xe /Users/Shared/Jenkins/tmp/hudson7751940722564747051.sh
touch jUnit.xml
```

I don't really know how to access Jenkins to touch the file.(one of the solution to "failed: Test reports were found but none of them are new. Did tests run?").

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <testsuites>
  <testsuite name="PerformanceTest" errors="0" skipped="0" tests="2" failures="1" time="10.74" timestamp="2016-05-24T10:23:58">
  <testcase classname="PerformanceTest" name="testSmoothness" time="15" jank-percentage="75">
     <failure message="Too many jank frames." />
  </testcase>
  <testcase classname="PerformanceTest" name="testResponseTime" time="1.3" response-time="0.3">
  </testcase>
 </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank You!

Comment: So, what does your XML look like? I assume, there is a timestamp in it, you have to update or Jenkins wouldn't recognize it as changed.

Comment: @SevenEleven I've edit my question. How to modify it to make it possible to  generate the result

Comment: [Source](https://github.com/jenkinsci/junit-plugin/blob/f4b06246ca9da51c93969fa402f828e9f664e015/src/main/java/hudson/tasks/test/DefaultTestResultParserImpl.java). There is a timestamp check but looks like it works on file timestamps (last modified) and uses a jitter of 3000 (presumably milliseconds). The JUnit plugin is ignoring test XML output that is older than the buildtime of the current build minus 3 seconds.

If the test run and the JUnit plugin run are more than 3 seconds apart, the plugin will ignore the files.

Comment: One may also ignore the timestamp check (see l.118) but I don't know how to enable/disable this setting; hopefully this is possible at all and not only during plugin compile time.

Comment: @StefanHanke Thanks! I've solve it! Appreciate your help!

Comment: I've copied the comment as an answer. Please accept it s.t. others see this issue is solved.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(copied from my comment)

[Source](https://github.com/jenkinsci/junit-plugin/blob/f4b06246ca9da51c93969fa402f828e9f664e015/src/main/java/hudson/tasks/test/DefaultTestResultParserImpl.java). There is a timestamp check but looks like it works on file timestamps (last modified) and uses a jitter of 3000 (presumably milliseconds). The JUnit plugin is ignoring test XML output that is older than the buildtime of the current build minus 3 seconds. If the test run and the JUnit plugin run are more than 3 seconds apart, the plugin will ignore the files.

Comment: hai Stefan, what is exactly the solution? You mentioned the issue is solved? What did you solve? I am running into similar issues.

Comment: Set the system property `hudson.tasks.test.TestResultParser.ignoreTimestampCheck` to true